# in jQuery/JavaScript how do I exit a for loop when specific conditions are met

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that once I find the "date" in the JSON Object, my for loop keeps ticking. I assume this is causing me to enter the "Else" part of the condition everytime.

I am fairly new to JavaScript/jQuery.

Output from Console

```
report-generation.js:443 Entering Else Loop for 02/13/2017. The date from the JSON file is 02/6/2017
report-generation.js:434 Entering If Loop for 02/13/2017. The date from the JSON file is 02/13/2017
report-generation.js:443 Entering Else Loop for 02/13/2017. The date from the JSON file is 02/20/2017
report-generation.js:488 02/6/2017 date from JSON. Selected Date is 02/13/2017
report-generation.js:488 02/13/2017 date from JSON. Selected Date is 02/13/2017
report-generation.js:488 02/20/2017 date from JSON. Selected Date is 02/13/2017
```

My JavaScript Code

```
// Get Information Technology Division Manager Schedule
for (var i = 0; i < informationtechnologydivisionmanager.length; i++)
{
    var emailAddressParts = informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].name.split(' ');
    var emailAddress = emailAddressParts[0] + "." + emailAddressParts[1] + "@example.com";
    var createLink = "mailto:" + emailAddress + "?subject=Schedule for " + dateFromInput + "&body=This is a template. Please remove these lines and add your own";

    if (informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].date == theSelectedDate)
    {
        console.log("Entering If Loop for " + theSelectedDate + ". The date from the JSON file is " + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].date);
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerName').html("<a href='" + createLink + "'>" + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].name + "</a><br>");
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerTitle').html(informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].title);
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerMondaySchedule').html(informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].mondayAM + "<br>" + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].mondayPM);
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerTuesdaySchedule').html(informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].tuesdayAM + "<br>" + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].tuesdayPM);
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerWednesdaySchedule').html(informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].wednesdayAM + "<br>" + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].wednesdayPM);
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerThursdaySchedule').html(informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].thursdayAM + "<br>" + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].thursdayPM);
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerFridaySchedule').html(informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].fridayAM + "<br>" + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].fridayPM);
    } else {
        console.log("Entering Else Loop for " + theSelectedDate + ". The date from the JSON file is " + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].date);
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerName').html("<a href='" + createLink + "'>" + informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].name + "</a><br>");
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerTitle').html(informationtechnologydivisionmanager[i].title);
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerMondaySchedule').html("No Schedule Set" + "<br>" + "No Schedule Set");
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerTuesdaySchedule').html("No Schedule Set" + "<br>" + "No Schedule Set");
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerWednesdaySchedule').html("No Schedule Set" + "<br>" + "No Schedule Set");
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerThursdaySchedule').html("No Schedule Set" + "<br>" + "No Schedule Set");
        $('.informationtechnologydivisionmanagerFridaySchedule').html("No Schedule Set" + "<br>" + "No Schedule Set");
    }
}
```

MyHTML Code

```
<table id="informationtechnology" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6" class="caption">Information Technology</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Name</span></th>
            <th><span>Monday</span></th>
            <th><span>Tuesday</span></th>
            <th><span>Wednesday</span></th>
            <th><span>Thursday</span></th>
            <th><span>Friday</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="lalign"><span class="informationtechnologydivisionmanagerName"></span><span class="informationtechnologydivisionmanagerTitle" style="color: navy;text-align: center;"></span></td>
            <td><span class="informationtechnologydivisionmanagerMondaySchedule"></span></td>
            <td><span class="informationtechnologydivisionmanagerTuesdaySchedule"></span></td>
            <td><span class="informationtechnologydivisionmanagerWednesdaySchedule"></span></td>
            <td><span class="informationtechnologydivisionmanagerThursdaySchedule"></span></td>
            <td><span class="informationtechnologydivisionmanagerFridaySchedule"></span></td>               
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [break;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) is the usual way

Comment: if (condition) break;

Comment: willl break get me out of the if loop or the for loop?

Comment: Unrelated to what you're asking, [there's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). (In your code you have shown an object, but no JSON.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main keywords used to get out of a loop are `break` and `continue`.
`break` stops the loop completely and jumps to the line after the loop.
`continue` just stops the current iteration, and jumps to the beginning of the loop, continuing with the next iteration.

So what you need is `break`